# Extending or overriding a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

We have a function on form binding in JavaScript,something like

```
var formBind = function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    // some ajax post and validation portion here
    return false;
};
```

The formBind is used on many pages as `$('form:visible').submit(formBind);`

Now I have a requirement to only apply additional confirmation box on a particular page before submission. How can I add that functionality with minimum changes on the original code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nest your original formBind within a new function

```
var formBind = function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    // some ajax post and validation portion here
    return false;
};

var additionalFormBind = function( event ) {
    var result = null;
    // do additional work before original formBind
    result = formBind( event );
    // do additional work after original formBind
    return result;
}

$('form:visible').submit(additionalFormBind);
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, you can add as many parameters as you like to a function call or definition - only the ones that are supplied or match will be used.  You can change the function like this:

```
var formBind = function( event, showConfirm ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    if (showConfirm) {
        //logic to display confirmation, followed by a call to the original ajax post if required
    } else {
        // some ajax post and validation portion here
    }
    return false;
};
```

All your existing places that call this function won't supply this parameter, so it will be undefined, and the `if` will evaluate to `false` and leave the original functionality intact.  In new code, you can supply it as `true` or `false` as required:

```
$('form:visible').submit(function(e) { return formBind(e, true); });
```

Comment: Poster states that additional confirmation is needed.  The above code revision will run other code instead, rather than in addition to.

Comment: @JeremyFriesen I'd intended it more as an example of how to supply optional parameters to a function, but yes - have edited it to put it more in the context of the OP question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's data parameter to pass through extra information.

`$('form:visible').submit({ showConfirm: true }, formBind);`

Then check in the handler:

`var formBind = function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    if(event.data.showConfirm) { 
        // confirmation code goes here.
    }
    // some ajax post and validation portion here
    return false;
};`

Comment: Nice.  I hadn't seen the [`eventData` parameter](http://api.jquery.com/submit/#submit-eventData-handler) before - this is a much cleaner solution since the function is being called as a jQuery event handler.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks. Honestly, I think every answer is perfectly good - just a matter of preference :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `formsubmit` function with a new function that contains confirmation..

```
$('form:visible').submit(confirmAndSubmit);

var confirmAndSubmit = function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return (window.confirm("Are You Sure?"))?formsubmit(event):false;
};
```